# Change network response in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, manifest.json

Is it possible to catch the response from the network using the Chrome extension and change it?

webrequest blocking doesn't work in manifest v3. declarativeNetRequest also cannot change the data inside.